# How Come mysqld -u root will start my database, but mysqld_safe -u root gets "Permission denied"?

Tags: mysql

The title is fairly self-explanatory. I am a mysql newbie, so any help is appreciated. I can boot my database and everything works fine using mysqld. When I try to run mysqld_safe in a similar fashion, I get permission denied. Here is what I am running:

`mysqld -u root`

*Everything boots up fine*

`mysqld_safe -u root`

*I get permission denied (output below)*

`140404 14:10:55 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log'.
 140404 14:10:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from         /opt/boxen/data/mysql
/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/mysqld_safe: line 132: /opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log: Permission   denied
/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/mysqld_safe: line 176: /opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
140404 14:10:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/boxen/data/mysql/My-iMac-  25.local.pid ended
/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/mysqld_safe: line 132: /opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied`

When I check the error logs, here are lines 132 and 176, respectively:

`2014-03-27 09:03:11 798 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';`

`2014-03-27 09:03:32 1062 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled`

Strangely, these lines from the error log have a different timestamp. I have a feeling I am overlooking something dumb, but I have no idea.

Comment: 1) provide logs, 2) how do you know you're running `mysqld` in a similar fashion - what does that even mean? can you provide exact line?

Comment: My mistake, the error I had in the question was unrelated: I was looking in the wrong spot in the error log. I've explicitly included what I am putting into the console. It must be some kind of permissions rule I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Seems that you have permissions issue on file `/opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log`. What is your distro (seems OSX) ? What if you run `mysqld_safe` with sudo ?

Comment: I was able to fix this with the following:

`sudo chown root /opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log`

Then I booted with:

`sudo mysqld_safe --user=root`

It appears to be working now.

Comment: I am not surprised. This is what i was suggesting with my previous question in comments

Comment: Yes you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks krisFR.

Comment: @Doug Mill Ok great, thanks. To avoid leaving a questions without an answer that will float here for years i will write one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have a permissions issue on file `/opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log`.

Check for permissions on file `/opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log`.

You should try to make this file belongs to root user :

- `chown root /opt/boxen/log/mysql/error.log`

Then execute `mysqld_safe` using `sudo`.